# Package javascript project using npm and dividing it up into node modules to create a dependency tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a javascript project which is used as a utility in another project and I want to package it using npm so that more projects can use it. The project structure I created is:

```
Project/
|-- src/
|   |-- main.js
|   |-- index.js
|
|   |-- extensions/
|   |   |-- core-1.js
|   |   |-- ...
|   |   |-- core-n.js
|   |   |-- other-1.js
|   |   |-- ...
|   |   |-- other-n.js
|   |
```

The main file creates an object with some utility functions in it which is used by the extensions. The index.js file takes all the objects and functions from extensions and main and put it into a single namespace to export it. What I want is when anyone install this node module they should be able to use the utilities in the main file and core extensions. If they want to use other extensions they should have the ability to explicitly require the other extensions. Is it good idea to create separate node projects for other extensions which has dependency one the main project? or is there any other way provided by npm or node to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `require("<your-module>")`, node.js loads a file mentioned in `main` property inside your `package.json` or `index.js` by default. There is a way to load individual files from a particular package. Just append your file path after your module name prepended with slash.

In your example extensions can be individually loaded like this

```
var u1 = require("Project/src/extensions/other-1");
var u2 = require("Project/src/extensions/other-2");
```

Only `other-1` and `other-2` extensions will be loaded in variables `u1` and `u2` respectively.

You should ensure that appropriate files are loaded in `index.js` and `main.js`.

Here is an example node module https://github.com/juzerali/require-demo

You should try installing project as a node module and try playing with it to understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach and it worked well for me. Just a note my extensions depends on the core, so I had to require the core inside the extension file.